# ¿Es "tronco" una grosería en Hispanoamérica?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, hispanoamérica, dialectos, lenguaje-peyorativo

> —¡Hola, **tronco**! ¿Cómo te va?
>   —Estoy bien, ¿y tú?
>   —¡Guay!

¿Es "tronco" una grosería en Latinoamérica?. Y también ¿en qué parte de España se usa esa expresión?

Comment: Que sepa yo, *tronco* salió del habla urbana española ochentera. Como muchos insultos, con el debido tono y contexto, todos lo entenderán con el sentido familiar, aunque no lo usen (incluso sin haberlo escuchado antes). No sé si la palabra queda en uso como insulto leve en las Américas.

Comment: Tronco: En Colombia, jugador de fútbol que se mueve como un tronco, o sea poco ;-)

Comment: Sólo en España se utiliza para referirse a otra persona en sentido de camaraderia, al igual que otras formas tales como: "colega", "tio", "primo",  etc. En Latinoamérica, como bien lo menciona @DGaleano, sólo se utiliza para referirse a los futbolistas que son tan malos que asemejan la movilidad de un tronco. De hecho en España existe un equivalente para el significado Latinoamericano de "tronco", que sería "cono".

Comment: Aún se usa, aunque poco, en la zona de Madrid. En cuanto a grosería, debe indicarse que en España no lo es. Es un tratamiento informal.

Comment: En México (por lo menos en Ciudad de México) no es palabra soez.

Comment: Acá en México, en el norte más que nada, algunos decimos "ya estoy hasta el tronco", es como decir "ya estoy harto" o "ya estoy colmado hasta la médula"

Comment: There are enormous regions in Spain where the Madrid meaning is understood when listened to, but never spoken.

Answer (score 6):

En Colombia no es una grosería.  Es un sinónimo de *lerdo*, *lento*.  Es antónimo de *ágil*.

Por ejemplo:

> Ese es un equipo de troncos...

Refiriéndose a un equipo de jugadores de fútbol, indica que el equipo es malo porque los jugadores son lentos.

Comment: En Chile también se usa en ese mismo sentido.

Comment: En Guatemala lo he escuchado de la misma forma.

Comment: En Colombia, se usa "tronco" para referirse a una persona con poca habilidad para realizar algo; otro ejemplo aparte del mencionado sobre jugadores, es cuando alguien sabe poco o nada de bailar, se le dice "es un tronco para bailar".

Answer (score 4):

Es el equivalente a decir en Argentina "es de madera". Como dijo otro comentario, es porque son lentos, o directamente y hablando mas general, no es bueno en lo que está haciendo.

Comment: *Ser de madera* es mucho más común hoy en día; *ser un tronco* suena más antiguo.

Answer (score 3):

Es variado, hay una que acá en Centroamérica se usa mucho:

**ser un tronco de**

Ejemplos- 1 ese señor es un tronco de marido. 2 esa señora es un tronco de madre.

Ambas son correctas, y quieren decir que la calidad del señor como esposo, y la  calidad de la señora como madre, es de muy alto valor...  o sea, decirle a alguien que es 'un tronco de x cosa'  es poner a la persona en muy alta estima.

Answer (score 0):

En España "tronco" se utiliza en varias expresiones, de esta manera decimos  "dormir como un tronco", es decir, dormir de forma profunda durante largo tiempo. También "tronco" como alguien inerte, aburrido, o que le da pereza hacer cualquier tipo de actividad. ¡Tío no seas tronco y anímate! Ya veras como lo pasamos bien en el concierto.

Por otra parte, "tronco" se utiliza en el lenguaje coloquial al dirigirnos a otra persona como sinónimo de amigo, colega o tío,

Ejem - ¡Oye **tronco**!, ¿por qué no salimos esta noche de fiesta?.

Por regla general, "Tronco" no se entiende como grosería en España, a no ser que vaya acompañado de un tono despectivo o hiriente.