# ¿Cómo ha llegado "tronco" a ser sinónimo de tío / colega / amigo?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, españa

Hoy uno de mis compañeros de trabajo (angloparlantes) me ha saludado con un "Ey hombre", que era por supuesto una traducción literal de "Ey *man*!". Como sé que que este en particular tiene un nivel aceptable de español (creció en Nueva York en un barrio con mayoría de Puertorriqueños, y tiene un nivel de español decente, un poco oxidado) he querido ayudarle a mejorar un poco su español y explicarle que nosotros no usaríamos "hombre" en ese contexto y favoreceríamos "tío" o "tronco".

Le he explicado que "tío" [evolucionó a una forma cariñosa de incluir a alguien "en la familia"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22848/5481) y de ahí a designar a alguien con el que puedes tener más o menos familiaridad.

Lo de "tronco" no he sabido explicarlo con seguridad. Buscando en este stack y fuera, lo más que he podido encontrar es un comentario de guifa en [¿Es »tronco« una grosería en Latinoamérica?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16556/5481) que indica que

> *tronco* salió del habla urbana española ochentera. Como muchos insultos, con el debido tono y contexto, todos lo entenderán con el sentido familiar

Sin embargo, no se explica (posiblemente porque no era lo que se preguntaba y esto era solo un comentario tangencial) cómo llegó `tronco` a adquirir el significado coloquial de "amigo" o "compañero".

En el DRAE [tronco,ca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=amwpZjT) tiene entre otros el significado de

> 8. m. Persona insensible, inútil o despreciable.

Aunque no se recoge el coloquialismo de la acepción de "amigo" o "colega".

Lo más lógico entiendo que sería que estuviese relacionado con la cuarta acepción del diccionario

> 4. m. Cuerpo humano o de cualquier animal, prescindiendo de la cabeza y las extremidades.

"Eres un *tronco*" como un insulto blando que acaba transformándose en apelativo cariñoso, y que de ahí se adaptase también al femenino de "tronca" para "amiga". Sin embargo, no he podido contrastar ni verificar esta hipótesis.

¿Sabe alguien cómo ha llegado "tronco" a ser sinónimo de tío / colega /amigo?

Comment: No me sorprendería, como casi se puede usar *cabrón* en España con el mismo valor.. Pero vamos, *hombre* se puede escuchar en la península, por lo menos por Asturias se acorta como *ho*, *¡¿Qué tal **ho**?!*

Comment: No tengo la solución -- y me parece una pregunta interesante -- pero quería comentar algo.  No dudo que estés acostumbrado a saludar con *tío* y *tronco*, pero jamás he oído estos saludos ni en México ni en EEUU; y es más, el saludo que tu compañero de trabajo te hizo es *muy normal* entre los latinos de EEUU.

Comment: No estoy nada convencida de que la sorpresa en "Hey, man" [no "ey"] no podria ser: "Olá, hombre" en español. Hey, man muestra sorpresa, y hombre en español también. RAE: 8. interj. U. para indicar sorpresa o asombro, o con un matiz conciliador. ¡Hombre, no te enfades! Hombre, no hay que ponerse así, María.  Estes usos serian Man en inglës.

Comment: O: Hombre, que dices? Como vamos? Por ejemplo.

Comment: En Colombia "tronco" no tiene nada que ver con amigo, ni colega, ni tío, ni hermano.

Answer (score 0):

No puedo darte una respuesta 100% valida pero creo que deriva de:

> ¡Qué pasa flipao!

Una manera de saludarse común entre los adolescentes de los años 80. Como es una expresión de barrio tampoco es difícil saber de dónde sale, pero se acercaría al uso de un despectivo suave como afectivo. Es bastante común usar expresiones como *tontito* o similar, pero por el contexto adquieren un significado cariñoso.

Y desde ahí tendríamos dos posibles desviaciones

### 1. Tron

Y en la salida de la película [**TRON**](https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film488334.html) en 1982 se sustituiría la palabra *flipao* por *tron* en referencia a esta. Y de ahi quedaría la frase

> ¡Qué pasa tron!

Luego por uso acabaría en:

> ¡Qué pasa tronco!

### 2. Surferos

El término tronco se usó mucho tiempo como coloquio entre los surfistas para hablar sobre alguien sin flexibilidad y poco manejo sobre la tabla. De ahí se quedaría porque casi cualquier insulto en español puede acabar según contexto en algo afectivo.

Comment: Me recuerda [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17107/1674) donde marcan del origen de _qué fuerte_ en la película _Regreso al futuro_.

Comment: Curioso, yo siempre pensé que fue al revés: que de "tronco" se pasó a "tron", por vagancia.

Comment: Sinceramente, me resisto a creer que la peli de _Tron_ tenga algo que ver con esto. Yo creo que la expresión empezó con "tronco" y se abrevió en "tron". De momento el primer texto que he encontrado con "tron" es de 1980: "Lo cual que tú con el rollo del desencanto, que es ya una pasada, tron, y a cobrar el subsidio de desencanto."

Comment: tron viene mucho antes de la película: 
https://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/CLAC/article/download/60518/4564456547400/

Comment: "TRON" es una abreviatura de la expresión en inglés "trace on", que es el comando en el lenguaje BASIC para iniciar una traza o registro de las instrucciones que se ejecutan en un programa de computador

Answer (score 0):

Que yo sepa, al igual que otros términos del lenguaje coloquial urbano, el origen de "tronco" como colega y amigo, se encuentra en la jerga carcelaria, al menos de la jerga carcelaria española.

En lenguaje carcelario, los troncos eran los compañeros de sumario, los encausados en un mismo proceso. En la cárcel "tronco", era sinónimo de amigo, casi un hermano. Es decir, se trataba de un término afectuoso.

Answer (score 0):

La palabra "tronco" en España tiene varios significados, desde la expresión  "dormir como un tronco", con el sentido de dormir de forma profunda durante largo tiempo.

En algún deporte cuando se dice de alguien que es un "tronco" significa que es grande, torpe y poco ágil en sus movimiento.

También "tronco" es utilizado para alguien inactivo, con aparente escasa fuerza, aburrido, o que le da pereza hacer cualquier tipo de actividad.

Por otra parte, "tronco" se utiliza en el lenguaje coloquial al dirigirnos a otra persona como sinónimo de tío, amigo o colega o tío.

La nueva acepción de "**tronco**", como colega, amigo, hombre o tío, no vendría de lo que se ha comentado hasta ahora, pues su inicio hay que buscarlo en el periodo de "**La Transición**", cuando en 1978 el Cuerpo de Policía Nacional antecesor al actual Cuerpo Nacional de Policía actual, sustituye a la antigua "Policía Armada" de la época franquista.

Los miembros de este nuevo cuerpo fueron popularmente conocidos por el apelativo de **"maderos**" por el color de su uniforme, en contraste con el uniforme color gris empleado durante la época franquista. Fue está palabra "**madero**" la que dio origen a "**tronco**" (madero como sinónimo de tronco), y por antonomasia se extendió al resto de la sociedad. Durante un corto periodo a los policías también se les llamo, "troncos", "Los maderos, sobre todo la secreta,  amigos de los colegas, también eran troncos" Era normal hacer bromas cuando ibas vestido de marrón, "vas como un tronco", referido al color de los trajes de la policía de la época.

Posteriormente la palabra "tronco" se acorto a "tron", colega a "coli", pasota a "passa", compañero a "ñero" o "eñero", y otros tantos hoy ya en desuso.

Por último, respecto a la palabra "flipado" /"flipao" que he visto antes, de la cual se dice que posiblemente proceda la voz "tronco, esto no es cierto. Se dice "**flipado**" para referirse a una persona que parece estar bajo los efectos de la droga o simplemente que se comporta de forma extraña, loca o de conducta cambiante (colgado). Esta palabra, no tiene nada que ver con **"tronco**" ya que "**flipado**", españolizado, provendría del inglés "**flip out**". Verb. flip vuelo, enloquecer, perder la "chaveta" (cabeza). El adj. de flip es "flippant", para nosotros "flipante". En este sentido, aquel saludo cariñoso, ¡Qué pasa flipado (flipao)!, viene a decir ¿Cómo estás "colgao"?